# How to elect a leader in the grid?

Tags: grid, gridgain

I am evaluating GridGain 6.1.8. My objective is to have only one node in the grid (called leader) doing some specific job. The requirements are:

- The leader node must be elected automatically by the grid.
- Only one node could be the leader at a time.
- If the leader dies the grid must elect another node as the leader.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with GridGain 6.2.0-rc2 release GridGain has `GridProjection.oldest()` method which can be used as a leader. It satisfies exactly the requirements you are listing.

Also, you can find more information in this post: [Gridgain leader election pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23387291/gridgain-leader-election-pattern)